# How to handle the feature differences between my training and test data

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-selection

So, currently my training and testing sets start with 669 features, many of which are categorical and will need to be one-hot encoded.

After one-hot encoding both sets, I found that the training set has additional features.

I'm not quite sure how to handle this but I feel like I have three options:

1. Remove these features from training set so both match up
2. Add these features to the test set and produce synthetic data.
3. Before I train my model, use some dimensionality reduction technique (PCA) and use the same number of components for training and testing.

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you did one-hot encoding on Train & Test data separately. Maybe, combine them and then apply the encoding or try [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) on them separately and use the following code [symmetric difference](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/symmetric_difference) for sets to get differences and then assign 0 for the missing columns.

```
    missing_cols = (set(train.columns)).symmetric_difference(set(test.columns))
    for c in missing_cols:
         titanic_test[c] = 0
```

Comment: Hot encoding should be done separately on train and testing set, as you don't know about test set/instance.

Answer (score 0):

Create dummies for both training and testing set separately. Exclude features which are in testing but not in training set, as they are not used in training. Include features which are in training set but not in testing set and fill data corresponding to them using "mean","median","mode" of training set or zero.

Something like this can be done:

```
Xdummies=pd.get_dummies(X,drop_first=True)
features=Xdummies.columns
xtest=pd.get_dummies(Xhold,drop_first=True)
test_feat=xtest.columns
exclude=list(set(test_feat)-set(features))
include=list(set(features)-set(test_feat))
Xtest=pd.concat([xtest.drop(exclude,axis=1).reset_index(drop=True),pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,xtest.shape[0]),data=0,columns=include).reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
```